# Multiple lines of curved text in SVG

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Is there a way in SVG of drawing multiple lines of text within a single `<text>` element that follow the same path contour? Here is the closest I have been able to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="text_0_path" d="M 100 150 A 100 100 0 1 1 300 150"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#text_0_path" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18px" text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">
            <!-- 157.075 is the center of the length of an arc of radius 100 -->
            <tspan x="157.075">Here is a line</tspan>
            <tspan x="157.075" dy="20">Here is a line</tspan>
            <tspan x="157.075" dy="20">Here is a line</tspan>
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Here is the output (in Chrome):

[image: Curved text]

This is *almost* what I want. The problems:

- I would like each line of text centered at the top of the arc, not to start the text there. It seems like the `text-anchor` attribute is being forgotten when the `x` value is specified in a `tspan` along a path. (This is *not* the case with straight text; the `text-anchor` attribute is remembered.)
- Each successive line of text is crunched, as if following a concentric path. I would like each line of text to follow the same contour, as if the path were simply translated in the `y` direction by the height of the font.

I know I could just create three separate `<path>` elements and associate them with three separate `<text>` (or `<textPath>`) elements, but it would be really nice to keep all the text logically together using `<tspan>` elements for later applications.

Or is this *supposed* to work but there is a rendering bug in Chrome? (unlikely, IMO)

Comment: Your example works as expected in Opera 11 and Firefox 4, that is: the text is centered on the curve.

Comment: @Erik: Good information; thanks! Does it also translate the contour of the path (as desired), or project it down like Chrome, causing the crushing together of subsequent lines? (If you want to put your response in an answer, I think it is worthy of some credit.)

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell if you want the text rendered on concentric circles or if you simply want it translated. If the former, then you may want to experiment with letter-spaccing attributes on your t-span elements. This will add tracking to your characters pushing them further apart. I tried the following, but alignment between lines is lost for some reason:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="text_0_path" d="M 100 150 A 100 100 0 1 1 300 150"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#text_0_path" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18px" text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">
            <!-- 157.075 is the center of the length of an arc of radius 100 -->
            <tspan x="157.075">Here is a line</tspan>
            <tspan x="157.075" dy="20" letter-spacing="2">Here is a line</tspan>
            <tspan x="157.075" dy="20" letter-spacing="4">Here is a line</tspan>
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

However, if you want the latter (concentric circles), this appears to work in Safari and Chrome on the Mac:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="text_0_path" d="M 100 150 A 100 100 0 1 1 300 150"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#text_0_path" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <g font-family="Arial" font-size="18px">
        <text text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">Here is a line</textPath>
        </text>
        <text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 20)">
            <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">Here is a line</textPath>
        </text>
        <text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 40)">
            <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">Here is a line</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I know you were shooting for tspans only, but as you said, it seemed to reset the startOffset values.

HTH,
Kevin